# LDAP Error While Creating Entry via Eclipse

Tags: ldap

Error getting in eclipse add entry.

Error while creating entry

- [LDAP: error code 32 - NO_SUCH_OBJECT: failed for MessageType : ADD_REQUES
  java.lang.Exception: [LDAP: error code 32 - NO_SUCH_OBJECT: failed for MessageType : ADD_REQUEST Message ID : 48

  Add Request :

  Entry

  dn[n]: dc=user

  objectclass: domain

  objectclass: top

  objectclass: person

  dc: user

  sn: james

  cn: common-name

: ERR_268 Cannot find a partition for dc=user]

```
at
```

org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.checkResponse(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:1280)

```
at
```

org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.access$600(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:109)

```
at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper$6.run(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:928)

at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.runAndMonitor(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:1175)

at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.checkConnectionAndRunAndMonitor(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:1109)

at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.createEntry(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:950)

at org.apache.directory.studio.ldapbrowser.core.jobs.CreateEntryRunnable.createEntry(CreateEntryRunnable.java:224)

at org.apache.directory.studio.ldapbrowser.core.jobs.CreateEntryRunnable.run(CreateEntryRunnable.java:124)

at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.ui.RunnableContextRunner$1.run(RunnableContextRunner.java:112)

at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
```

[LDAP: error code 32 - NO_SUCH_OBJECT: failed for MessageType : ADD_REQUEST
Message ID : 48

```
Add Request :
```

Entry

```
dn[n]: dc=user

objectclass: domain

objectclass: top

objectclass: person

dc: user

sn: james

cn: common-name
```

: ERR_268 Cannot find a partition for dc=user]

Comment: This is badly formatted and badly constructed question. Actually it does not contain any question at all. I won't downvote it as you're new user, but you should try to make it readable for answers. Error you get is probably because entry you're trying to add has invalid contents, i.e. set of variables ( ObjectClass violation ). You should paste LDIF for entry you're trying to add. Expect downvotes from other users soon..

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have change the variables, Again I am facing LDAP: error code 32 - NO_SUCH_OBJECT: failed for MessageType. I am new to LDAP.

Comment: Please, paste ENTRY you're trying to add ( remember to obscure password if needed ), and use newlines to format output instead of lazy copy-paste..

Answer (score 0):

Error message states there is more than one STRUCTURAL ObjectClass in the object, what causes ObjectClass violation. Examine set of ObjectClasses (array of values for ObjectClass attribute) , and compare with some other existing entry. Now I was able to read it from your output, but now you have cut off too much, including actual error, so the error itself is not visible, only in edit history..

You should probably read LDIF/LDAP manual page, to understand how entries are constructed. ObjectClass attribute can contain many classes, but only one STRUCTURAL and remaining ones AUXILIARY. Various objectClasses require one or more other attributes. Some classes are permitted to be used as STRUCTURAL or AUXILIARY by schema.

"None such object" when adding entries may indicate various things, e.g. including bad DN (nonexisting branch under which you're trying to add your new object.)

I would strongly suggest to dump other entry ( use copy as text option in DirectoryStudio ), change one or two variables, and re-add. Possibly by shell, to understand how LDIF is supposed to look like. Once you'll be able to add one entry successfully, you'll be able to add bunch of them. Read about LDIF format and how schema requirements/validation works.

EDIT: Now your entry contains probably invalid DN ( should be like dn: dc=james, ou=someDepartment, c=someCountry ), it is unlikely RDN to be rootDSE. That is why you receive "invalid partition" error. Find out about difference between full DN (distinguished Name) and RDN ( relative distinguished name ) of entry.

You have three object classess, each of them MAY or MUST contain specific attributes, possibly some of them must be present as SINGLE one in the entry etc. Look at existing entries, and start with copying one as text and apply some simple modification, e.g. changing some username or other attribute with new value ( all occurences within the entry ).

Good luck :)

Comment: Oh come one, it's everywhere. E.g. here is a trivial example entry, and shown how to add it using ldapadd utility. http://www.ghacks.net/2010/09/02/adding-ldap-entries-from-the-command-line/